# php/ajax vote up down

Tags: php, ajax, vote

and sry in advance because i'm new here and i'm completly new in php/ajax coding.

I use a free script (Ajax vote up/down) from [this site](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/voting-up-down-script-ajax_s2)

I have a simple php page for my shoutcast server to show the song played

```html
<?php
 
  require_once "inc.php";
 
 $array = array(); // Let's store our shoutcast variables into an array.
 
 $array['host'] = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx"; // Your Shoutcast Host
 $array['port'] = "xxxx"; // Your Shoutcast Port
 $array['extra'] = "/admin.cgi?sid=1&mode=viewxml&page=1"; // The bit that follows in the url to access the xml of the stats
 $array['user'] = "xxxxx"; // Admin username (Default is usually "admin")
 $array['password'] = "xxxxxxx"; // Admin Password
 
    $radioStats = new radioStats( $array['host'], $array['port'], $array['extra'], $array['user'], $array['password']);
  
    $returnStats = $radioStats->returnStats(); 
    $song = $returnStats['currentSong'];
     ?>
<div align="center">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<link href="votingfiles/voting.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="votingfiles/voting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(function(){cache_clear()},54000);
 });
 function cache_clear()
{
 window.location.reload(true);
}
</script>             
 <div id="radio_stats">

 <?php
  
  if( $returnStats['serverStatus'] != 0 ) {
  
 ?>
  <?php
  if( $returnStats['currentSong'] != "" ) {
   echo $returnStats['currentSong'];
  } else {
   echo "Undefined";
  }
  ?></div>
 
  <br /><br />
    <div class="vot_updown1" id="vt_$song"></div> 
 <?php
  }
  else {
 ?>
 This radio server appears to be offline.
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

My problem is : 
All request Php/ajax/mysql works but actually when i make a vote, it's registered in the db like :

**vt_$song  1   0**

How can i do to get the real name of the song like the original php request do :

**echo $returnStats['currentSong'];** or **echo $song;**

To register in the db like :

**vt_Kidd Guti-Step Everything 1 0** (or any other song played)

Example : [HERE]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line the `$song` is not parsed as PHP so the literal text `$song` is showing:

```
<div class="vot_updown1" id="vt_$song"></div>
```

Try:

```
<div class="vot_updown1" id="vt_<?php echo $song; ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Thks a lot it work now! i have tried to add the "<?php echo" but i made wrong syntaxe. Now i will never forget the right syntaxe. Thanks you!

Comment: @albatror hey friend if answer of Chaim is work please accept the answer or vote it